# How to minimise and expectation with respect to a parameter?

Tags: entropy, kullback-leibler, maximum-entropy, extreme-value

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable with distribution $G$. Let $H(X;\theta)$ be a parametric function with $\theta \in \Theta \subset {\mathbb R}^p$. I want to maximize the function

$$\varphi(\theta) = \int H(x;\theta) dG(x).$$
I know that this has some relationship with the Kullback Liebler divergence and the Entropy,  but I don't know how to proceed to maximize this function. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: For me the question is unclear? What is the expected result? If the functions are not given how can you take an integral? But maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @keiv.fly I just want to find some general procedure as I do not want to fix H and G for the moment.  Hopefully related to maximizing the Entropy. Of course, if $\varphi$, then that's a Calculus I matter.